# Space colony based upon faith?

Tags: society, space-colonization

In the game Alpha Centauri, one of the potential leaders you can play is based on faith. This vaguely means they're focused on recruiting into the flock. But how exactly would s space colony based on a religion work, assuming there are other colonies on the same planet?

Comment: Would you be able to clarify how your space colonies are different from communities on Earth?

Comment: This reminds me of the Halo franchise, where the alien covenant was held together by religion. you may look at that for reference: https://halo.fandom.com/wiki/Covenant_religion
  They were basically worshiping a really old-extinct alien species called forerunners, who were tooooo much advanced in tech that their creations left behind seemed like magic to them.

Comment: Look into our history. Religion was a significant driving factor behind setting up the colonies outside the Old World.

Comment: What aspects of a colony do you want to focus on? Governing? Politics? Relationship with other colonies on the same planet? Power structure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think humanity has reached the Moon and set a foot in space precisely thanks to the competition between the two "faiths" of the XX century: capitalism and communism.

Generally speaking, a group works better when there is some glue cementing the people and their effort together. A common faith can be such glue, making the individuals feel part of a group, sharing a common goal. The faith won't directly propel the spaceships, but it will make possible for people to work together at it.

Answer (score 0):

The [final section of A Canticle for Leibowitz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Canticle_for_Leibowitz#Fiat_Voluntas_Tua_(%22Thy_Will_Be_Done%22)) has as the major plot point the religious order launch a self supporting space colony for continuity in the event of nuclear war on earth.